# Initialization of an array of struct

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize an array of structs.
The struct contains all integer values, and I would like to set their initial values all to 0.

First I did it the long way like this:

```
void initializeTcsPointer( TestCaseSet* tcsPointer )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_TEST_CASE_SETS; i++ )
    {
        tcsPointer[i].numPass = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numFail = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numPWU = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numFWU = 0;

        tcsPointer[i].numRFA_Pass = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numRFB_Pass = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numRFA_PWU = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numRFB_PWU = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numRFA_FWU = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numRFB_FWU = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numRFA_Fail = 0;
        tcsPointer[i].numRFB_Fail = 0;

    }
}
```

It works, but then I wanted to do it the short way:

```
void initializeTcsPointer( TestCaseSet* tcsPointer )
{
    TestCaseSet newSet = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_TEST_CASE_SETS; i++ )
    {
        tcsPointer[i] = newSet;     
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work. I'm wondering how come?

Comment: I get a Debug error from Visual Studio when running the code

Comment: Make default constructor for `TestCaseSet` that will initialize members to 0

Comment: It's probably an index out of range error.  The struct assignment should be fine.  Also, you can omit all the zeroes in your newSet assignment as those will be implicitly supplied.

Comment: TestCaseSet* with MAX_NUMBER_TEST_CASE_SETS...sure it's C++? To read as: first of all let's write using C++ features (list? vector?). You'll save yourself from many many of these (pointer) errors. Side note: what's wrong there may depend on assignment operator, indexing or anything else...

Comment: You are right, it's not so much C++ as it is C. I'm still trying to learn C++

Comment: Anyway, the error isn't clear from that code. Yes you may change it to workaround but it is still somewhere there (you allocated less items than MAX_NUMBER_TEST_CASE_SETS? there is an error in the assignment operator?). Let's post more core and...the debug error message you get!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Lol4t0, Add a ctor for you struct:

```
struct TestCaseSet {

    TestCaseSet()
    : numPass(0), numFail(0), numPWU(0) {}

};
```

Add your other variables like above.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the type will no longed be an aggregate or a POD like this. This may not matter, but is worth pointing out.

Comment: -1 Sorry but this doesn't explain WHY it fails.

Comment: @Adriano Oh, I knew. But OP has not provided what error occurred.  The code provided by OP seems fine.  So I couldn't tell from the code.  The only thing I could do is provide a C++ way to do this init :)

Comment: Yes, that's the point. If, for example, it crashes because tcsPointer has less elements than MAX_NUMBER_TEST_CASE_SETS then how class is declared won't make any difference.